# Fixate scroll in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I "fixate the scroll" at line 27 as khan did in this excel spreadsheet?

https://www.khanacademy.org/downloads/buyrent.xls

Comment: I don't think people here will be keen to download arbitrary Excel file, especially that it's in the legacy format which can contain malicious macros. Please describe your issue.

Comment: I haven't looked at the linked file, but could you be referring to [freeze panes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP001217048.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source [Freeze or lock rows and columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP001217048.aspx)

> To keep an area of a worksheet visible while you scroll to another area of the worksheet, you can lock specific rows or columns in one area by freezing or splitting panes.
>
> When you freeze panes, you keep specific rows or columns visible when
>   you scroll in the worksheet. For example, you might want to keep row
>   and column labels visible as you scroll.
>
> On the worksheet, do one of the following:
>
> - To lock rows, select the row below the row or rows that you want to keep visible when you scroll.
> - To lock columns, select the column to the right of the column or columns that you want to keep visible when you scroll.
> - To lock both rows and columns, click the cell below and to the right of the rows and columns that you want to keep visible when
>     you scroll.
>
> On the View tab, in the Window group, click the arrow below Freeze
>   Panes.
>
> Then do one of the following:
>
> - To lock one row only, click Freeze Top Row.
> - To lock one column only, click Freeze First Column.
> - To lock more than one row or column, or to lock both rows and columns at the same time, click Freeze Panes.